# Lagging the f-curve

Tags: fcurves

I have a line with 5 points in an animation. I also have a f curve. The Z of the first point on the curve is tied to the f curve. I would like to tie the second point's z-axis to the f curve but with a lag of say 10 frames. And so on for the other 3 points. I could do this with 5 f-curves with each being 10 frames offset but this seems like there should be a different solution.